# DeviceUseTrigger doesn't result in long running background task

Tags: windows-10-mobile, background-task, microsoft-band

I'm using DeviceUseTrigger to get a "near-permanent" connection to the Microsoft Band. Explained in http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1036512/Achieveing-Indefinite-Background-Execution-with-th

The method, described in the codeproject article, works perfectly in debug mode (without draining the battery). But running my app from the store results in a stopped backgroundtask; Windows 10 mobile stops the task due to some failing OS policy condition.

Does anybody found a workaround for this backgroundtask restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Band does not initiate connections with channel A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F. Given that, we are uncertain what causes such RFCOMM trigger to start the background task.

Overall, today there is no supported way to solve this problem on Microsoft Mobile in RFCOMM trigger way using only the Band. Any successful experiments would hurt the behavior of Health Application.

What can help is any other device opening RFCOMM connection to the phone and a trigger set up for that connection.

Besides that it is not clear what "works perfectly in debug mode" means. When Visual Studio debugger is attached, the background tasks stay, helping the developer. Without debugger they get cancelled by OS.

Comment: The RFCOMM deviceusetrigger does start the background task correctly when my band is connected. But the problem is the WM10 OS cancelling the task. I don't see a reason why the OS is doing this (no huge cpu load)? What do you mean with "hurt the behavior of the Health application", I don't think my app conflicts with the Health App?